# Require files no seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Preciso organizar o meu arquivo seeds.rb, então criei um namespace onde irei adicionar minhas classes ex:

```
module Seeds
 class Apple
   def self.run
     puts 'teste'
   end
 end
end
Seeds::Apple.run
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente, mas eu preciso separar minhas classes em arquivos separados semelhante à estrutura abaixo:

```
db
  seeds
    Apple.rb
  seeds.rb
```

e no seeds.rb:

```
require 'db/seeds/Apple'
Seeds::Apple.run
```

e ele retorna um erro que não consegue carregar o arquivo, o que poderia ser?

Comment: Conhece essa gem? https://github.com/james2m/seedbank Não resolve seu problema?

Comment: Obrigado, isso vai resolver.

Comment: ok, vou postar como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a gem http://github.com/james2m/seedbank, ela "turbina" o funcionamento do seeds.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada.

Comment: @AndersonBS Concordo!

Answer (score 1):

> Utilizar código abaixo para incluir todos os arquivos da pasta **seeds**
>
> Utilizar **Rails.root** para obter o caminho completo to arquivo.

```
# Include ruby files
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].each do |filename|
  puts load(filename) if File.exist?(filename)
end
Seeds::Apple.run
```

Comment: Além da resposta do Takitani funcionar, ela tem um problema, gems gems gems gems, e gems demais não é muito legal não. Tenha certeza antes de usar uma gem que você realmente precisa, e com esse código aposto que ele faz o que se pede.